# Flexbox - <a> tag breaks layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Having issues with a Flexbox banner.
When I add an anchor tag to make the whole banner a link the flexbox layout breaks, I tried setting the anchor tag width and height to 100% but that didn't work either.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
main,
menu,
nav,
section,
summary {
  display: block;
}

a {
  background-color: transparent;
}

a:active,
a:hover {
  outline: 0;
}

#banner-section {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 3em 1em;
}

.card {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 14px 0px rgba(148, 148, 148, 0.35);
}

.card a:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 16px 20px 0px rgba(148, 148, 148, 0.61);
}

.info-container1 {
  background-color: plum;
}

.info-container2 {
  background-color: pink;
}

.card-info {
  padding: 1.2em;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .wrap {
    max-width: 50em;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .banner {
    display: flex;
  }
  .info-container1 {
    width: 50%;
    flex: 1;
  }
  .info-container2 {
    width: 50%;
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="banner-section">
  <div class="wrap">
    <article class="banner card">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="info-container1">
          <div class="card-info">
            <h2>Container 1</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, usu ei exerci bonorum praesent, duo cu dolorem adipiscing vituperata, in vel atomorum ocurreret. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet etc etc... </p>
          </div>
          <!-- .card-info -->
        </div>
        <!-- .info-container -->
        <div class="info-container2">
          <div class="card-info">
            <h2>Container 2</h2>
            <p>Ea autem perfecto prodesset mea, sed case hendrerit te, tale vidit accusam ex mel.</p>
          </div>
          <!-- .card-info -->
        </div>
        <!-- .info-container -->
      </a>
    </article>
    <!-- .banner .card -->
  </div>
</section>
```

Basically I need both columns to be equal in height and width and wrapped in the `<a>` tag so the whole banner becomes a clickable link. If I remove the anchor tag the layout works as intended.
What is it I'm missing here?

Comment: add this:   a{display:block}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An element with `display: flex` arranges it's *children* in a flexible box layout.

The only child of the `<article>` is the `<a>` so that is the only element being laid out in the flex box.

Put the link around the article instead. Then the div elements will be the article's children.

Answer (score 8):

You can try this:

```html
<a href="#" style="display: contents;">
```

I had a similar problem and solved it this way.

Comment: Can you site w3spec which mentions this behaviour? Is it an artefact? MDN says `display; contents` will take the anchor tag out of web accessibility tree -- this might be bad for seo and assistive technologies.

Comment: This was the answer that worked for me, not the answer marked correct.